# My bootstrap carousel is not working properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I don't know why my carousel's not working properly, can anybody tell me how to fix this issue.
My codesandbox link :- https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-heyrovsky-8yucf?file=/src/Prompts.jsx

Comment: None of your buttons have any `onClick` attributes. Can you add relevant code to your question and explain what *exactly* the issue is?

Comment: I am using bootstrap and jquery cdn for carousel, that's why there is no need of onClick.

Comment: But you're creating a React app; that's not how this works I'm afraid. Here's the React way of doing this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Comment: can't we use bootstrap carousel in react project?

Comment: Yes, but you need the version that is written for React. React is not just a different way to generate HTML, it's a fully fledged JS framework that maintains your entire frontend. You should best forget jQuery for now, because react-bootstrap does not use jQuery like you're used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `carousel-inner` multiple times but in reality you only need to render that one time and render `carousel-items` multiple times

I refactored your code a bit too so it only talks to the relevant dom elements

Also, I somewhat agree and disagree with christ here. Yes you should opt for react-boostrap library for this kind of stuff because they provide components for every item however if you ever use it then do explore the rendered version of it on the browser and then you will realize that its the same as a simple bootstrap library with same class names etc. But its mostly depends on how you use any library.

Anyway, I hope this codesandbox helped you if didn't then let me know. Happy coding

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tu-55u2h?file=/src/Prompts.jsx